# How can I handle data/json that I retrieve from my API Webservice (ExpressJS)?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to NodeJS and ExpressJS. I created an AuthController which handles the login post.

```
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password");
    if (!user) {
        const error = new Error("Wrong Credentials");
        error.statusCode = 401;
        throw error;            
    }

    const validPassword = await user.validPassword(password);
    if (!validPassword) {
        const error = new Error("Wrong Credentials");
        error.statusCode = 401;
        throw error;      
    }

    const token = jwt.encode({id: user.id}, config.jwtSecret);
    res.send({user, token});
} catch(err) {
    next(err);
}
}
```

I would like to use this method in my web application to let the user login. If the user succesfully logs in, I get a json response in my browser with the user and the token. That's not what I want. The url for the api login is: /api/auth/login. I created a function in my web application:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
    var apiResponse = await authController.login(req, res, next);
    res.render('profile.ejs', {user: apiResponse.user});
});
```

I keep getting the error that authController.login is not a function. My question is how can I use the method from my API and use the response in my webapplication? Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it** like this code below:

```js
router.post('/login', authController.login, async (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('profile.ejs', {user: apiResponse.user});
});
```

‍ Please read the documentation about [Express Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

**Updated: Middleware**

Make sure your authController looks like this code below:

```js
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
      const email = req.body.email;
      const password = req.body.password;

      const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password");
      if (!user) {
          const error = new Error("Wrong Credentials");
          error.statusCode = 401;
          throw error;            
      }

      const validPassword = await user.validPassword(password);
      if (!validPassword) {
          const error = new Error("Wrong Credentials");
          error.statusCode = 401;
          throw error;      
      }

      const token = jwt.encode({id: user.id}, config.jwtSecret);
      // passing your data to next function
      // you can change exampleData with the 'variable' you want
      req.exampleData = { user, token }
      next();
  } catch(err) {
      next(err);
  }
}
```

If your authController is same root ("folder") with the your routes, than make it's look like this:

```js
const { login } = require('./authController');
```

So, now, you can call the authController like this:

```js
router.post('/login', login, async (req, res, next) => {
  // your data: "user" and "token" from middleware
  const { exampleData } = req;
  console.log(exampleData);
  res.render('profile.ejs', {user: exampleData});
});
```

I hope it's can help you .

Comment: I tried that. But I get: Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]. That happens when I try to run the app.

Comment: That's because you are wrong in calling and using the middleware variable. You can see the sample code above, I've been updated it.

Comment: I updated with your code. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Error came from calling your middleware. `router.post('/login', login, async (req, res, next) => { //... })`. Make sure you are correctly calling the `login` variable. That's why I give you an example `const { login }`. Because I've been try the code above and it's working fine.

Comment: I feel stupid. I don't get it. I do it like this: ```const {login} = '../controllers/authController';
router.post('/login', login, async (req, res, next) => {
    const { response } = req;
    console.log(response);
    res.render('profile.ejs', {user: response.user});
});``` my code is the same. and I use next() instead of sending json in my login method

Comment: You still get error like this: **Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined].** or another errors

Comment: Please try to stop your express server and run again.

Comment: Already tried that. Here some links to my code: https://imgshare.io/image/kUqhx
https://imgshare.io/image/kUhZg
https://imgshare.io/image/kUTgl
https://imgshare.io/image/kUY67

Comment: If you can provide a github link, than I will check it out for you.

Comment: Here a temporary link to my zipped project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HtWBOHhoKTRGBTqgPjw5GOanG_fC20rw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You got some error, because in your `routes/index.js`, you make something like this: `const {login} = '../controllers/authController';` **you forgot** to using `require`. So, you have to add require and than it's well looks like this: `const { login } = require('../controllers/authController');`. **Please see my answer above, there have a `require`**